# Is it possible to get ccnet 1.4 to use svn 1.6?

Tags: svn, cruisecontrol.net

I see that my version of ccnet has a directory named svn-win32-1.4.6 (which i assume it uses to pull from SVN, which is on another server..)

is it possible to get ccnet to use a newer version of SVN client tools?

also, if so, would the new client tools pull just fine from SVN 1.4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a CCNET 1.4.3 implementation pointing to SVN 1.4.6. When we upgraded SVN to 1.6, everything continued to work. So YES.

Answer (score 1):

CruiseControl.Net does not ship with SVN included, you must have installed it yourself. And yes, it does work fine with svn from 1.6 branch.